# Idiom for partially-forward-declaring a struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, forward-declaration, idioms

In C++, when we define classes or structs, we make some fields private and some public:

```
struct foo {
   public:
       int x;
   private:
       float y;
}
```

. In C we cannot do this, but we can use forward declaration, and getters. in `foo.h`:

```
struct foo;

foo_get_x(struct foo* f);
```

and in `foo.c`:

```
struct foo {
       int x;
       float y;
}

foo_get_x(struct foo* f) { return f->x; }
```

Now, suppose that for certain reasons (e.g. performance) I want to be able to access x directly, without a function call, from code which only sees `foo.h`. I would like some way to have `x` be defined somehow, and for the rest of struct foo to be hidden from me. I was thinking maybe there's some trick with unions that I could do; or maybe working with

```
struct foo {
   int x;
   char* more_data[];
}
```

kind of a construct, which I've noticed here and there. What would you suggest?

Comment: Maybe you should consider link time optimization, e.g. with GCC compile *and link* with `gcc -Wall -flto -O2`

Comment: if you are going to break hiding the members of the struct for one particular member, why bother to hide any of the members at all?

Comment: If your only concern is a visibility, do nothing. Visibility rules are about making your code more robust; yet any "tricks" to implement it in C are to make it error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

First, you are trying to use `C` as `C++`. **Don't!** However, if you are bent  on doing this, the [PIMPL idiom](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=pimpl%20idiom) could be used here:

foo.h

```
struct foo_impl;

struct foo {
  int public_a;
  foo_impl *impl;
};

int foo_get_x(foo const *f);
```

foo.c

```
#include "foo.h"

struct foo_impl {
  int x;
};

int foo_get_x(foo const *f) {
   return f->impl->x;
}
```

Of course this add an extra level of complexion and you need to take extra care to properly initialize and destroy the associated `foo_impl` object.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
/* public header */
struct foo
{ 
  /* "public" parts */
};

/* elsewhere */
struct bar 
{
   struct foo fooPart;
   /* other  stuff */        
};
```

You can freely cast a pointer that points to a `struct bar` to `struct foo*` type and back to `struct bar*`, this is guaranteed to be well-defined.

So you can write functions that allocate a `bar` and return a `foo*`, and functions thst accept a `foo*` but work with a `bar`.

This is how early OO software was written in C.

Comment: @Matt Why should it? The idea is to use some of the foo members directly, which you don't normally get to do with forward-declared foo.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to do within C because you are confusing lexical and semantic scoping.

Here's one way (untested), and admittedly disgusting:

in `foo.h`

```
struct foo_impl {
       int x;
       float y;
}

struct foo;

inline int foo_get_x(struct foo* f) { return ((struct foo_impl*)f)->x; }
```

Comment: Why untested? I guess nearly everyone does this (feeling a slight sense of shame). It works OK, until some day one changes struct alignment...

Comment: @Matt: I meant I had not run the specific code through a compiler.